# How to invoke a JS function from several controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have several controls in a table, the IDs and functions are generated in each row of a table like this:

```
<select id="data_01" onclick="open_details_01()">...
<select id="data_02" onclick="open_details_02()">...
<select id="data_03" onclick="open_details_03()">...
```

I need just one function like:

```
function open_details_ + *index* ()
{
}
```

When the name of the function starting always with "data_"

Comment: Are you sure you want a bunch of different functions? Why not create one function and pass that function an argument telling you which thing you're opening?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, with all this answers I can complete my code. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this one of two ways:

1. use `eval`: `eval( functionName + num + "();" )
2. You can make the function as part of an object and then call it as a member: `myObject[ functionName + num ]()`

To do the second one:

```
    var obj = {
      open_details_01: function()
      {
        alert( "1" );
      },
      open_details_02: function()
      {
        alert( "2" );
      },
      open_details_03: function()
      {
        alert( "3" );
      }
    };

    var num = "01";
    obj[ "open_details_" + num ]();
    num = "02";
    obj[ "open_details_" + num ]();
    num = "03";
    obj[ "open_details_" + num ]();
```

Fiddle of second way: https://jsfiddle.net/69Lk5baa/

Answer (score 1):

If the structure of the `select` control always have id sequence `data_01, data_02 ..` , you can use jquery `startsWith` selector:

```
$('[id^=data_]').on("change",function()
{
  alert(this.id);
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/zwv9h4c9/2/

Comment: Perfect, is exactly was I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jquery, you can use the the attribute starts with selector method to attach an event.

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$(document).on('click', "button[id^='data_']", function(){
    alert('clicked');
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/usav3dor/

Comment: you don't need button[id^='data_'] , just [id^='data_'] would do it since jquery doesn't supports same id policy.